# Passing php-objects to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to know if it is possible to create a php-object and use it and its methods in my JavaScript.
For example, I have the following php-script:

```
<?php  
       class Foo
       {
           public function bar()
           {
                //do something here
           }
       }
 ?>
```

Then I could send an AJAX-request to the server and grab an instance of Foo:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/Foo/Foo.php",
    data: {
        action: "get-object"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data){
        alert("My Foo object: "+data);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Did not work");
    }
});
```

Of course I would have to extend Foo.php a bit so that it returns me an instance of class Foo.

I tried that and it did not work, my data variable is always empty.

So is there another approach to get an instance of a php-class and call methods on it in Javascript?

Comment: php.net > json_encode > read it **carefully**.

Comment: Have you got a JS class called `Foo`? Data structures can be transferred between programming languages, but you can't pass methods in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only run the PHP code on the server, so each time you want to call a method on it from JavaScript, you will need to make a new HTTP request to the server.

This will require keeping the object in existence across multiple requests. You can do this by storing it in a session variable (you might need to explicitly serialise it first).

---

An alternative method would be to:

- reimplement the class using JavaScript
- extract the data from the PHP object
- send that data to the client
- construct a JavaScript object from the data
- call the methods on that JavaScript object

Obvious, this will only work if the methods do things that you can achieve with client side JS (or you will have to involve more Ajax).